# Por que no funciona el wire:model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

tengo este problema, mi wire:model no funciona bien tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<form class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" value="{{$usuario[0]->personal}}" wire:model="id_personal">
  </div>
  <label for="">Aporte</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="id_concepto_pago" wire:model="id_concepto_pago">
      <option>Elija una Opcion</option>
      @foreach($concepto as $con)
        <option value="{{$con->id}}">{{$con->descripcion}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('id_concepto_pago') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Cantidad</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="cantidad" placeholder="Ingrese una Cantidad">
  @error('cantidad') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Fecha</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" wire:model="fecha">
  @error('fecha') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Referencia</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="referencia" placeholder="Colocar 0 si fue pago personal">
  @error('referencia') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Imagen</label>
  <input type="file" name="imagen" value="" wire:model="imagen">
  @error('imagen') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
</div>
</form>
```

Todo funciona bien. pero en la parte donde está: `"<input type="text" value="{{$usuario[0]->personal}}" wire:model="id_personal">"` cuando le coloco lo del wire:model el valor desaparece, pero cuando se lo quito el input recibe el valor correcto, si se dan cuenta en los otros bloques uso eso de forma similar y no me dan problemas, es solo éste.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Saca la etiqueta form del formulario, esa etiqueta hace que el formulario recargue.

```
<form class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Saludos